# How to print integers calculated on loop variable pgffor

Tags: pgffor

I written loop like this:

```
\foreach \n in {1,...,5}{
        2*\n+1
        \myfigure{c\n.png}{Code \n}
        2*\n+2
        \myfigure{r\n.png}{Result \n}
    }
```

On lines containing mathematical expressions, I need to calculate them as integers. How could I do this? I added only `pgffor` package.

Comment: \n is a macro, not a counter.  You can use `\pgfmathparse{int(2*\n+1)} \pgfmathresult`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Can you write up an answer?

Comment: It wouldn't be more than a code fragment (not testable).